# use mongoose reserved field names

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm building an app that already has a lot of dependencies and use the word `collection` as a resource (document) and a property (key) that reference that resource. But for <s>mongodb</s> mongoose this is a reserved word, and I can't use it.

I tried use the virtual feature, with no success:

```
var ProductModel = new mongoose.Schema({
    ...
    _collection: {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId}, // I can't put collection here
}, { 
  toObject: {
    virtuals: true
  },
  toJSON: {
    virtuals: true 
  }
});
ProductModel.virtual('collection').get(function() { return this._collection; });
ProductModel.virtual('collection').set(function() { return this._collection; });
```

Returning me an error

```
 Cannot read property 'scope' of undefined
    at model.Object.defineProperty.set [as collection] (/path/my-app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:1231:58)
```

How can I make this work, maybe using middlewares in a simple way? That I could apply to any model?

Comment: why the reserved names aren't something like `___collection` or `_|_collection`?

Comment: `virtual` properties should be defined on the schema, not the model. Can you update your question to provide a more complete example?

Comment: `collection` is not a reserved keyword in MongoDB itself. `db.collection.save({'foo':'bar'})` works perfectly fine in MongoDB 3.0

Comment: Sorry @JohnnyHK, I call it models in my app, I will update the code

Comment: You are correct @Jaco, this is a `mongoose` problem http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema.reserved

Comment: @Guilherme do you find a workaround for this issue?